# Toggle divs open and close in Visual Studio 2012 (outlining)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to toggle open and close divs in Visual Studio 2012.  The functionality is in my Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, but I don't know how to get it on the new one.

Normally you just press the plus/minus button to open/close divs. It's on the left side of the screen to the right of the line numbers, but this doesn't even show up on my Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that outlining is enabled.  The option is typically found in the Edit menu under Outlining->Start Automatic Outlining.

Comment: +1: Note: I find with my VS2012, that sometimes the outlining markers (the +/- boxes, etc.) don't show up until you collapse a tag once (like with Ctrl+M,M) - even when Outlining is already enabled.  Not sure if this is because of plug-in I have installed or alike, but be warned. ;)